# EF execution of Oracle stored procedure with DATE parameter loses hours/minutes

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have a simple stored procedure using DATE as an input:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_time(myTime DATE) IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE time = myTime;
END;
/
```

This has been added to my EDMX using a function import, and the types mapped are Date on the SSDL side and DateTime on the CSDL.

The problem is when I run the procedure from .NET using a DateTime the hours and minutes are lost somewhere along the way:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 4, 3, 12, 15, 00);
var timeParam = new ObjectParameter("myTime", dt) : 
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("DeleteTime", timeParam);
```

This runs the stored procedure but deletes the rows where TIME = 03-APR-2013 00:00:00 instead of 03-APR-2013 12:15:00

Is there some bug in the Oracle client (I'm using 11.2.0.3.20)? Or am I doing something wrong above?

I also tried using TIMESTAMP as the input type of my procedure, but then I get this error when calling the function:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the edm type of the time parameter?

Comment: What does `timeParam.ParameterType` show ?

Comment: Just a wild guess - could it be that the param is sent to oracle as a string? if so, the oracle will convert it according to nls_date_format which is probably `DD-MON-YYYY`. You can try (just for the check) to change your stored procedure to `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE time = to_date(myTime, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')` and the param type to VARCHAR2 (this is not the right solution - just a check)

Comment: ParameterType is {Name = "DateTime" FullName = "System.DateTime"}.  I'm not sure how to check the EDM type, is it not the SSDL type seen in the EDMX which is "Date" as I said before?   I will try the VARCHAR2 suggestion when I get chance...

Comment: I tried using VARCHAR2 as the input parameter type, but the time portion is still lost during the to_date conversion.  However if I set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT in the beginning of my procedure then I can get it to work, but only if I keep using VARCHAR2 to pass in the DateTime - this feels like one workaround too far though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem trying to execute a Oracle procedure using entity framework. So I did like this to pass a Date parameter:

```
var objects = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyObject>("BEGIN My_procedure(to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh24:mi:ss')); END;").ToList();
```